# Sys path ImportError: no module named leap

Tags: python, module, path, importerror, leap-motion

I've been trying to figure out this error for a couple of days now and its driving me crazy. Im working on some code for the LeapMotion device in python on Canopy. However i keep getting this error:
    Import Error: no module named Leap
I've tried adding the path:

```
import sys
 sys.path.append("/ThisPC/OS(C:)/LeapMotion/Leap_Motion_SDK_Windows_2.3.1/LeapDeveloperKit_2.3.1+31549_win/LeapSDK/lib/x86")

import Leap, sys, thread, time
```

Ive also tried importing this path as a list, with each folder appended seperately.
But nothing is working for me. Please help, I've tried looking on dozens of forums and cant solve this. My Canopy is up to date (just installed it) and im working on windows 8.

Comment: You don't usually refer to third-party modules like that; you usually install them. Is there a setup.py provided?

Comment: Check that exactly the name of the module you are trying to import is the correct one(eg case sensitive and etc).The last option is uninstall and reinstall it using Python official way of installing modules.

Answer (score 0):

This line looks problematic:

```
sys.path.append("/ThisPC/OS(C:)/LeapMotion/Leap_Motion_SDK_Windows_2.3.1/LeapDeveloperKit_2.3.1+31549_win/LeapSDK/lib/x86")
```

That isn't a valid file path on any OS. Try removing the first few parts of the path in your string:

```
sys.path.append("C:/LeapMotion/Leap_Motion_SDK_Windows_2.3.1/LeapDeveloperKit_2.3.1+31549_win/LeapSDK/lib/x86")
```

Note that the Leap Motion SDK doesn't provide a module installed to one of the standard Python locations (or scripts to put the libraries there).